# Removing finished futures to keep their number constant

Tags: c++11, asynchronous, containers, bigdata, future

I have a program that needs to launch a large number of futures; specifically, more than `size_t`. A normal way to have many futures is to keep them in a container but since there are too many of them, I would have to remove the finished ones. The program needs to count the number of new lines in parallel.

This is what I want to work for `n>size_t`:

```
vector<future<int>> vf;
for(size_t i=0; i<n;++i){
  vf.emplace_back(async([&](){ return count_lines(part_of_an_array);});
}
double cnt=0;
for(auto i:vf) cnt+=i;
```

One way I thought of doing it is to keep a `vector<char> busy_f` (`vector<bool>` is probably not thread safe). As `count_lines` starts --> `busy_f[i_future]=0`, and when it would finish --> `busy_f[i_future]=1`.

Is there a faster approach?

Comment: `size_t` is not a number, it's a type. Do you mean "more than `std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max()`"?

Answer (score 1):

Creating the threads or even the futures "manually" in such cases is usually not a good idea, because it is difficult to create the "right amount" of them: remember you only have a relatively small number of actual cores/threads to execute on, and creating all the extra futures, which do not immediately map to a thread and just block and wait and take space in memory is wasteful.

I'd use some sort of higher-level parallelization primitive, like a 'parallel for' or a parallel map-reduce implementation.

I don't know what OS/compiler you're using, so I'm going to suggest to use TBB as a cross-platform solution. If you're on Microsoft stack, they have their own parallel library, which in some aspects is better than TBB.

In TBB they have a [parallel_reduce](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506154) template function, which looks exactly like what you need, and note what they promise:

> If the range and body take O(1) space, and the range splits into
>   nearly equal pieces, then the space complexity is O(P log(N)), where N
>   is the size of the range and P is the number of threads.

However, all ranges in TBB are limited to size_t... Maybe you can write an outer loop, which "makes" "chunks" of size_t elements from the larger problem, and then for each chunk you could call a parallel_reduce and sum up their results.

```
double result = 0;
for(BingNumber offset = 0; offset < n; offset += BigNumber(size_t_size))
{
   result += parallel_reduce( ... )
}
```